# How do I create a rule that publishes comments on node after 3 days?

Tags: 7, comments, rules

In Drupal 7, and I am trying to make a rule that publishes comments on a node 3 days after they have been created. I had a look at this [post](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/21683/how-do-i-create-a-rule-that-closes-comments-on-node-after-30-days) to see if I can do this in reverse.

Workflow:

> - A comment is created (unpublished)
> - The author has 3 days to publish or "*delete*" the comment (the comment actually just gets archived).
> - If no action has been taken after 3 days or it is not "archived" then publish the comment

My rule (I struggled to get this working so the Scheduled Evaluation Date is 30 seconds)
[image: My rule]

My rule component
[image: My rule component]

Am I on the right track or am I missing something?

Comment: cron is running? schedules creates in /admin/config/workflow/rules/schedule ?